# do some stuff after stylesheet has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose this css stylesheet:

**template.css**

```
p{color: red; margin: 0; padding: 10px;}
div{background: red; color: white;}
/*.....
and a lot of stylesheet rules
*/
```

And now after sometime I would **change to template.css rules**

```
p{color: red; margin: 0; padding: 10px;}
div{background: red; color: blue;}/* modified previous rules too*/
/*.....
and a lot of stylesheet rules
....
added stylesheet rules*/
```

---

**Now question starts here:**

I would like to check if my stylesheet has been changed or not:

```
var storedss = 0; //0 represents not changed (false)

//if stylesheet has been changed from previous state of stylesheet ??? 
//how to check ????

storedss = 1; // 1 represents changed (true)

//now perform some action
if(storedss){
//do stuff here


//and at last reset to 0
storedss = 0;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: how would the stylesheet be changed? via editor?

Comment: Is it like, initially you have inline style in html file and later you want to add external css?

Comment: just external stylesheet about what I'm talking.

Comment: And I know about clearing cache but I wanted to do something else....

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible. The Browser will parse the CSS file and apply to DOM Nodes. So, there is no comparison/tracking done by our javascript.

Only if you intentionally retain a backup copy of the style info of all DOM nodes, then you can compare and decide if it has been modified alter at some desired point.

Even then, other than clearing cache i do not know a way how to change it. The only other way is to reload the page.

Comment: This is not an answer... You should comment out